# Formik Setfield not updating array value while using Materail UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

when I retrive the data from the api it in the following format

`otherLanguages:[{code:EN,name:"English"},{code:MD,name:"Mandarin"}]`

Here I am trying to initialise the Autocomplete with the following data.

```js
initialValues: {
    otherLanguages: otherLanguages ? otherLanguages : []
},
```

But it seems like Autocomplete only accepts the values when its in the following format? Should I be transforming the values to fit the undermentioned format?

```js
[{value:"EN",label:"English"},{value:"MD",label:"Mandarin"}]
```

```
<Autocomplete
    getOptionLabel={(option: { label: any; }) => option.label}
    getOptionSelected={(option: { title: string; }) => option.title === 'dull'}
    id="tags-standard"
    multiple
    onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.target)}}
    options={countryLanguages}
    popupIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    renderInput={(params: any) => (
        <>
        <Label color={Colors.Grey900} fontSize="16px"  value="Other Languages"/>
        <StyledTextField
        {...params}
        InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start"></InputAdornment>
            )
        }}
        variant="standard"
        />
        </>
    )}
    value={formik.values.otherLanguages}
/>
```

I have tried to handle the event but the initial values never gets updated. Also, when trying to set the value for the autocomple from the formik initial state ,it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the data structure as you want, but modify some of attributes of `Autocomplete` as follows:

```
onChange={(e, value) => {
  formik.setFieldValue("otherLanguages", value);
  console.log(e.target);
}}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.code}
```

Also add an attribute `isOptionEqualToValue` like this:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.code === value.code}
```

And I think `getOptionSelected` is useless.

Hope it may help.

Comment: This does work.But on change gives a new array with updated values, and updated values seems to have different key value attribute compared to the existing ones